# Django Rest Framework - image serializer returns url with escape characters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I try to save an Image using DRF. It saves but in response after saving I receive broken link because of escape characters.

Response after saving looks like this

```
{
  "profilePic" : "http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000\/media\/Images\/profilePic_MnPwLVh.jpg",
  "user" : 31
}
```

My serializer and view

```
class ProfilePicCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    profilePic = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProfilePic
        fields = [
            'user',
            'profilePic'
        ]
        read_only_fields = ('user',)

class ProfilePicCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = ProfilePic.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfilePicCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

What can I do in order to get links in correct way, that will have no need to do additional processing in order to use ?

Comment: Escaping slashes is very weird. What is your MEDIA_URL?

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Comment: One dirty hack would be to change profilePic to `serializers.SerializerMethodField`. Then, in the `get` method for it you would have to manually build an url.

Comment: Try using `JSONparser` instead?

Comment: Also - have you tried not putting the field at all? Maybe the default setting for `ModelSerializer` would not make such a mess?